# Combine the results of 2 queries, where there is no join or union

Tags: php, sql

I would like to append the results of 2 queries into one result set.

```
SELECT n.member_no, n.surname, n.first_name
            FROM `names` AS n
            WHERE member_no = '1003';

SELECT s.registration
                FROM `system` AS s
                WHERE s.RECNUM = 1;
```

This must return one record with data from the names table plus data from the system (one record) table

```
Member_no | surname |  first_name  |  registration
--------------------------------------------------
  1003    |  Brown  |     Peter    |  My registration
```

Comment: what's the relationship of your registration and names table?

Comment: Why can't you use the tools meant for this? How is PHP involved? What DB system are you using?

Comment: How do you know what `RECNUM` value corresponds with `member_no`? This should be a table in the database, so that you can write a meaningful query. That way you don’t have to rely on contrived relations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CrossJoin`:

```
SELECT n.member_no, n.surname, n.first_name, s.registration
            FROM names AS n
            CROSS JOIN system s
            WHERE n.member_no = '1003' and s.RECNUM = 1;
```

Comment: This solution worked after I fixed up the WHERE n.member_no

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

we can correlate your `registration` and `name` tables based on `row_number()`. You may want to try below query.

```
SELECT rn.member_no, rn.surname, n.first_name, s.registration
FROM
    (SELECT member_no, surname, first_name, row_number() over (order by member_no) rn
            FROM `names`) n           
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT row_number() over (order by RECNUM) rn, registration
                FROM `system`) s on s.rn = n.rn              
WHERE n.member_no = '1003'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.member_no, n.surname, n.first_name,s.registration
FROM `names` AS n, `system` AS s
WHERE s.RECNUM = 1 AND member_no = '1003';
```